# How to Map files if I have fid in Drupal 6 table and field in Drupal 7 content type?

Tags: 7, migrations

I have a drupal 6 database in which custom table is used to store the details. In the custom table a column `fid` contains the `fid` of file.

I have migrated the files and it migrated successfully. I mapped the node fields to that fid. I have added the following code :

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_image', 'fid')->sourceMigration('ExFiles');
```

It showing me following message :

```
The specified file 3424 could not be copied to public://3424.
```

I want to know how to map files from custom table field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you also need to specify the file_class:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_image', 'fid')
  ->sourceMigration('ExFiles');

$this->addFieldMapping('field_image:file_class')
  ->defaultValue('MigrateFileFid');
```

This is explained in the [file migration](https://www.drupal.org/node/1819704) docs; without the class, the source is assumed to be a URI and not a fid.